# What is the image size limit for iPhone 3G using iOS 4.2?

Tags: ios, graphics, ios4, limit, graphics2d

My app uses an image 4000x2828 pixels, about 2.9 MB compressed.

It runs fine on iPhone 4S iOS 5, but silently stops working on iPhone 3G iOS 4.2.

The app runs fine if I change the image to another one 501x501 pixels, about 900 kB compressed.

Is there a maximum image size or memory limit on iPhone 3G or iOS 4.2 I should know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone 3G has supposedly 128 MB of working RAM; that size of image takes about 34 MB uncompressed (it has to be handled uncompressed). So, while I can't tell you the maximum image size, you could make a test program generating bigger images (start in increments of 100 px) until you get the error.

Edit: you may want to have a look at [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45883-handling-large-images.html) thread for a possible work-around.

Comment: excuse me, how do you can find the weight of the image (34MB) from the size in pixels (4000x2828)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## **Max Image Sizes depends on device:**

## 1024 x 1024

- iPhone 2g
- iPhone 3g

## 2048 x 2048

- iPhone 3gs
- iPhone 4
- iPad 1st

## 4096 x 4096

- iPhone 4s
- iPad 2
- iPad 3
  etc...

Source: http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2012/04/quick-tip-max-texture-size/

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure the max images sizes for non retina devices (excluding ipad) is 1024x1024. For retina devices and iPad it's 2048x2048.

Comment: OK. I'll try it next time I borrow an iPhone 3G. I'll go with those numbers for now. Thanks.